# Reload Page with CommandLink

Tags: inline-visualforce

I have an embedded Visualforce page on the Account object that shows a list of related custom object records. I have created CommandLinks for Edit and Delete and I am trying to get the Edit CommandLink to refresh the entire page after a record is edited and saved.  When I click edit, I am able to edit the record in a pop-up window, but when I click save it returns me to the previous view of the embedded VF page that contains the record's previous data, not the edited data.  Is there a way I can refresh the entire page after the edit?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AcctAddresses" tabStyle="Account" >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    
<apex:form id="frm">

        <apex:pageblock id="AddressList"> 

            <div style="margin-left: 30%;"><apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account_Addresses__c.New)}" value="New Address" oncomplete="window.open('/{AccountId}&retURL=(AccountId}')" reRender="frm"/></div>

            <br/> 

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!addresses}" var="addr" rendered="{!IF(addresses.size > 0, true, false)}">
                 

                <apex:column HeaderValue="Action"> 

                    <apex:commandLink value="Edit" style="color:#015ba7;" action="/{!addr.Id}/e?retURL={!Account.id}" oncomplete="window.location.reload();"/>

                    &nbsp;|&nbsp; 

                    <apex:commandLink value="Delete" style="color:#015ba7;" action="{!deleteAddress}" target="_parent" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this address?')">
                        <apex:param name="AddrId" value="{!addr.Id}" assignTo="{!DelAddrId}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                           

                </apex:column> 

                <apex:column value="{!addr.Primary__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!addr.Street__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!addr.City__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!addr.State__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!addr.Zip_Postal_Code__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!addr.Country__c}"/> 

            </apex:pageBlockTable>            

            <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(addresses))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel> 

        </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>     
    
</apex:page>
```